# Main navigation, classes on/off. HGelp understanding how this is built

Tags: .net, html, css, navigation

OK, so I am trying to figure out how this navigation works.  Somehow, the images on the navigation are triggered on/off depending what page the user is on.  For the life of me I can't figure out how this is set up to work.

Mind you, my development skills are minimal HTML/CSS.  For example, if I build a new .aspx page and include the mainnav.ascx I can't get the correct tab images to trigger on/off to where I need them to be.  Can anyone help explain to me how this functions?

```
<%@ control language="VB" autoeventwireup="false" inherits="MainNavigation,         App_Web_ez7cbqlr" %>
<div id="tabNav">
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="bottom" class="tabPos1-Off" id="tab0" runat="server">
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td align="center" valign="top" class="tabOff" id="tab1" runat="server" style="vertical-align: top;">
            <a href="/ourMenu_05-000.aspx" class="navLink">
                <asp:Image ID="imgOurMenu" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/tabMenuOff.gif" /></a></td>
        <td valign="bottom" class="tabOverlapOff" id="tab1Over" runat="server">
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td align="center" class="tabOff" id="tab2" runat="server" style="vertical-align: top;">
            <a class="navLink" href="http://blog.com">
                <asp:Image ID="imgExpress" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/tabOurBlogOff.gif" /></a></td>
        <td valign="bottom" class="tabOverlapOff" id="tab2Over" runat="server">
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td align="center" class="tabOff" id="tab3" runat="server" style="vertical-align: top;">
            <a class="navLink" href="customerCenter.aspx">

                <asp:Image ID="imgCustomer" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/tabCustCareOff.gif" /></a></td>
        <td valign="bottom" class="tabOverlapOff" id="tab3Over" runat="server">
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td align="center" class="tabOff" id="tab4" runat="server" style="vertical-align: top;">
            <a class="navLink" href="ordering.aspx">
                <asp:Image ID="img101" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/tabOrder101Off.gif" /></a></td>
        <td valign="bottom" class="tabOverlapOff" id="tab4Over" runat="server">
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td align="center" class="tabOff" id="tab5" runat="server" style="vertical-align: top;">
            <a class="navLink" href="skinnyUs.aspx">
                <asp:Image ID="imgSkinny" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/tabSkinnyOff.gif" /></a></td>
        <td valign="bottom" class="tabOverlapOff" id="tab5Over" runat="server">
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td align="center" class="tabOff" id="tab6" runat="server" style="vertical-align: top;">
            <a class="navLink" href="joinUs.aspx">
                <asp:Image ID="imgJoin" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/tabJoinUsOff.gif" /></a></td>
        <td valign="bottom" class="tabOverlapOff" id="tab6Over" runat="server">
            &nbsp;</td>
        <td align="center" class="tabOff" style="padding-left: 7px; vertical-align: top;"
            id="tab7" runat="server">
            <a class="navLink" href="faqs.aspx">
                <asp:Image ID="imgFAQs" runat="server" ImageUrl="images/tabFaqsOff.gif" /></a></td>
        <td align="center" class="tabPos7-Off" id="tab7Over" runat="server">
            &nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: its better to provide a working link..

Comment: http://www.coolbakers.com  and here is a new page with the (what I am assuming is the classes incorrectly turned on/off http://www.coolbakers.com/survey.aspx.  Knowing how this works overall would be a huge help, as I currently feel like an idiot, ha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All these tables are making me feel sick :)

This might not be the answer you're looking for, but it looks to me like the code is generated server-side, i.e. the correct html code is served from the vb code (server side) depending on which page you're on...

Since we'd have to do a lot of digging around to find out exactly how this works, this is my assumption.

Comment: I know. I didnt design this nav layout, but it is what I have to work with.  I believe it is server side generated also.  I didn't see a code behind file, so I am not exactly sure where this is, any ideas?

Comment: I think you'll save yourself a lot of time to just rebuild it :) Anyways, it really looks like some server-side weirdness happening here, since all `<asp:Image ` tag gets rendered into an html element with mouseover/off event handlers. So there has to be a "code behind" file. I'm no .net expert, so won't be off too much help in figuring out where it is. Sorry and good luck!

Comment: Thanks!  I appreciate your input!

Comment: No problem! Maybe to a "Find" in the root folder for some code you know gets rendered on the hover state or something. Maybe the results will bring up a server-side script file that you're looking for.